# Best practice for a multipage/form mvc web app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a project using ASP.Net MVC & EF5. The Model has a large enough number of fields that the app will need several pages to collect all of the data.

Once the data is collected it is submitted to a Web Service/WebAPI. (This can not be changed or I would use EF entities instead).

What is the best practive or best suggestion for persisting the data model from page to page as it is filled?

Comment: Let me just point out there is a project silk (part of a patterns & practices) available at http://silk.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could create one ViewModel class that each page uses (strongly typed view) and just store the fields that aren't being edited in hidden fields. Your controller would have an action method and view for each step.  When each step is submitted you return the View (along with the View Model) for the next step.

On the last page, you submit the View Model and save it.

Contoller code:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Step1(MyBigViewModel model)
{
     //do work
     return View("Step2", model);
}

[HttpPost]    
public ActionResult Step2(MyBigViewModel model)
{
     //do work
     return View("Step3", model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Step3(MyBigViewModel model)
{
     //save here
     return View("Success", model);
}
```

Another option is to use a "Wizard-like" UI on a single page. Here's one I've used before with success:

https://github.com/mstratman/jQuery-Smart-Wizard

Comment: Hi @Rob, This is a few months ago, but I could not get your first answer above to work. Every time the form on the "Step2" view is submitted, it returns to the HttpPost method for Step1. The URL stays as {Controller}\Step1.

Comment: is this a recognised design pattern? Isn't it a bit 'weird'? Is it best practice?

Answer (score 12):

**Question - 1**

> Why can't I use the `Domain Model` directly interact with View or Why
>   can't I Create a `View Model` and pass all `Properties` of
>   `Domain-Model`?

**Answer**

Let's say you have 50 fields in your class. I have implemented *Data Annotations* so *Required Fields* are also present. ok. I am in Step-1. I submitted the form. My *Post Action Method* said, Form can't be submitted !!!! Why???

It's because there are some *Required Fields* which are not the Part of Step 1. I have a Question from you. Will you like to keep all `Properties` as mention in other answer?
If you want to add all the properties in one `View-Model` then why one interact with 
Domain-Model directly as per the suggestion provided in other answer? So, adding all properties in one View-Model will be worst. right?

**Question - 2**

> What is the best practive or best suggestion for persisting the data
>   model from page to page as it is filled?

**Answer**

```
1. Use View Models with necessary properties only(that are required for 
   particular Step.). So there can be many View Models on the basis of 
   your Steps. This process will be very useful in long run 
2. Use AutoMapper to populate the info required for View Model from Domain Model.
```

Using `Strongly Types View Models`, once the data is sent to `Post Action Method` after then As per my knowledge you can use `TempData` to store the posted data. It is like a `DataReader Class`, once read, Data will be lost. So that stored data in `TempData` will become null after read.

```
var Value = TempData["keyName"] //Once read data will be lost
```

---

**Question - 3**

> The Model has a large enough number of fields that the app will need
>   several pages to collect all of the data.

**Answer**

So to persist the data even after the data is read you can `Alive` it like below

```
var Value = TempData["keyName"];
TempData.Keep();                   //Data will not be lost for all Keys
TempData.Keep("keyName");          //Data will not be lost for this Key
```

---

**Question - 4**

```
How will you handle the case when you have both Next and Previous Buttons?
```

**Answer**

`TempData` works in new **Tabs/Windows** also, like `Session` variable does.

You could use `Session` Variable too you are able to keep the data across Controllers/Area as well

Hope this post will help you alot.

Answer (score 1):

I actually came across this article , which was very informative and helped me :
https://blacklineit.com/2015/10/14/rolling-your-own-viewstate-in-asp-net-mvc/

Basically the article comes down to this : "The easiest and cleanest way I found to persist data between pages is to use the great Newtonsoft JSON library to serialize viewmodel into a single hidden field, and deserialize on POST requests. "

Read it to get the background and additional info.

Comment: Good but it's 404. 
Google has it: [https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:jIcY-L3-oqMJ:https://blog.blacklineit.com/2015/10/14/rolling-your-own-viewstate-in-asp-net-mvc&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us](google cache) 
- create partial models for each page with fields matching the fields on a model representing the whole form. 
- Validate page against the smaller partial model to enable use of built in validation.
- Use AutoMapper to map the mini model back to the full size model in your controller action and stuff it back into a serialized JSON field that you send to the next page.